# Use async implementation of a method in its blocking version

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have created a custom subclass of `Stream` with an implementation of `Read`.
The operations used in the implementation can make good use of the `async` API though, so I wanted to provide a `ReadAsync` implementation as well.

The methods share a lot of similar behaviour, and the easiest way to avoid code duplication would be to keep the logic in the `ReadAsync` implementation and use that in the `Read` implementation. This would look like this:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    return ReadAsync(buffer, offset, count).Result;
}
```

Would there be any implications with this approach? As the `Read` method should block on the current thread, I think it would perfectly fit the specification.

Thanks!

Comment: this might help: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would there be any implications with this approach?

Yes, this is the [sync over async anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx), and it should be avoided. The main reason for that is that it can easily cause **deadlocks**.

How could that be? Your internal `ReadAsync` is probably awaiting on an asynchronous operation to be complete, while you're blocking a thread. If this thread is for example, the UI message loop thread, it's currently blocked. When your `await` completes (assuming you didn't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally), it would deadlock when trying to marshal back the continuations onto it.

When writing async code, you will have some amount of code duplication, there is no getting around that. Attempt to reuse as much as you can. for example, if both code methods have a synchronous part at the beginning, you can extract that to a third method which both async and sync versions will consume.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very enlightening! :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation of your Async method - if it waits the current thread for something a deadlock will appear. Generally it is preferred to not block to wait for async methods.